# What is a nested prefab?

Tags: unity-game-engine, terminology

I'm getting links [to this post today](http://framebunker.com/blog/poor-mans-nested-prefabs/) all over the social media. It seems some people made a useful piece of code to work with "nested prefabs". This thing is somehow related to 3D game development, and specifically Unity3D, which evidently doesn't support<sup>(?)</sup> them out-of-the-box.

But what is a nested prefab?

Comment: I am guessing that it is a prefab that is added to the scene and then added to a parent object therefore making the prefab a child object?

Comment: FWIW, nested prefabs are now on the roadmap under "Research" https://unity3d.com/unity/roadmap

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A [prefab](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Prefabs.html) is basically a prototype of a `GameObject` (potentially a hierarchy of `GameObjects`), with the attached `Components` and their relatives sets of `serialized properties`.

When you put a instance of a `Prefab` into the scene hierarchy, we can say that you have a **instance of a prefab** in the scene (or a **GameObject linked to a prefab**). This is quite useful because if you modify the prefab itself, all the modifications are propagated to the linked prefabs in all the scenes.

Now, for what concern your specific question: `Unity` **doesn't support nested prefabs** natively. Prefab are atomic entities in such a way that you cannot specify hierarchical relations between them.

For example if you have 2 prefab `A` and `B`, and you create a third prefab `C` which has `A` and `B` as children, Unity will consider `C` as a completely separate prefab. So if you modify `A` or `B` the modifications won't be actually propagated to the prefab `C`.

Comment: It's worth noting that some of us prefer not to have nested prefabs, or that it should be an opt-in feature.  I know a few devs that create lots of temporary prefabs as a part of their workflow.  Often these temps are tweaked slightly when attached to different objects and it would not be fun to have to create a unique temp. for each tweak or to have to break the link manually every time.

Comment: @Jerdak: personally I implemented some editor extensions that support a nested prefab like mechanism. Unfortunately with some limitations.

Comment: Nice.  I'm working a similar function using the Editor drawers to give me some ability to tweak nested prefab properties either per object or tied back to the original prefab.

Comment: Just learned this the hard way. I had many instances of a prefab in one gameobject which I then saved as a prefab; suddenly all my instances lost their linkage with the original prefab which meant I could no longer update each of them by modifying the original.

Comment: Me too just now. Is there any good strategy to dealing with, say a menu prefab comprised of many buttons that are a button prefab. I want to still change button prefab properties.

Comment: there are some problems with nested prefabs as a concept which are the reason why Unity avoids to implement them: cyclic nesting, runtime nested prefab linking and unlinking.

Comment: Is this still true? "So if you modify A or B the modifications won't be actually propagated to the prefab C." because I just did it, and the changes were indeed propagated to C. Or am I misunderstanding something.

Comment: @Lestat: it's probably still true. It's been a while since the last time I used Unity3D, so I might be wrong. But nested prefabs are a huge change that probably won't happen soon. I could be wrong though. So if you have a specific example, feel free to post another question and I will try to look into that.

Comment: Actually I was just confused, I'm new to unity. The changes weren't propagated.